# Is it possible to change a ListView item and then update the ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to change a `ListView` item (via index position) and then update the `ListView` efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ListView` in combination with an [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html).

The [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) will better handle the updating of the `ListView` contents.

Create an [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and then set it on your `ListView`.

```
myListView.setAdapter(...);
```

[Here is a tutorial that should help you.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have posted no kind of code here only as an example to suggest which methods and classes you could use:

```
ListAdapter a = myListView.getAdapter();
Object a = a.getItem(YOUR_POSITION);
```